# Set form target to iframe in another page

Tags: forms, iframe

i have an issue, i need to post a form and set its target to IFrame.

```
<form  method="post" action='http://localhost:85/formpage.aspx' target="my_iframe">
    <input type="hidden" name="email"  value="" runat="server" />
    <input type="hidden" name="name" id="signer_name" value="" runat="server" />
    <input type="hidden" name="adminemail"  value="" runat="server" />      
</form>
```

its working fine if Iframe in same page in which form is.

i want to put iframe to another page is this possible. i mean to say lets have form tag in Page1.aspx and   iframe tag in Page2.aspx

```
              <form target="Page2.aspx/my_ifram">
```

something like that is possible ?

Reason to do this beacuse i have to press BROWSER back button twice to come back to calling page.

Application Working:

Page1.aspx in code behind i put data in session and then on Page2.aspx that holds Form and IFrame i read data from session and on window.load of Page2.aspx i submit Form to external website that fills Iframe. now if i press Back button on page2.aspx to go back to Page1.aspx i need to do it twice because in broswer history i get two requests of Page2.aspx

can someone help me?wat i m doing wrong or it is not possible. It always be two request and there is no way to put iframe in another page

Comment: I think this is only possible if you post data to your second page (the one hosting the iframe) , and in this page you pass the data to the iframe. Now the best starting point would be to think about getting rid of those iframes...

Comment: wat wld the best alternate of IFrame if u think i have to get rid of Iframe? bcz i need to show external page in to my Calling Page.

Comment: I'm not saying you can always get rid of the iFrames. But I personnally keep it as a last solution when all other options can't be used. It's hard to tell whether or not you're using the best alternative without knowing the project. The fact is that posting data the way you're planning to do is risky : it's hard to monitor if anything fails, which could be the case anytime the person responsible for the external page changes its code...

Comment: External application is created by me, and external application accepts form.  dats y m in this trouble i cant put in query string because data is sensitive.

Comment: if data is sensitive, you shouldn't consider POST  a safe transmission way. You should at least think about https AND adding a hash of the values + a secret key in your post variables... POST variables are easily read and overwritten, less easily than get variables, but still...

Comment: Have you considered posting the data using an ajax call, and treating the result in your calling page ? please note also that the back button of the browser shouldn't be considered as a navigation button... so if its behaviour is not user friendly, but still it is necessary for the user to go back, maybe you should consider adding a "go back" functionality to your page